# elastic beanstalk Enhanced Health Overview : memory is in use

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

it seems to me that the new elastic beanstalk Enhanced Health Overview always complaining about memory usage 
is there any real solution to by pass this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is _Too Broad_: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of enhanced health for elastic beanstalk environments, a low memory warning indicates that the processes running on your system are consuming too much memory. You should ssh to the instance and see the memory usage for individual processes. You might want to switch to a bigger instance type with more RAM if your processes take a lot of memory.

Comment: Is there any real problem for the system to always use 9X% memory, provided it's stable it seems like it should be fine (shouldn't have a warning).

Comment: That is correct. It is not always a problem. In some cases this does indicate a memory leak. Sometimes kernel low memory killer can kill random processes if it runs out of memory. If it is stable then it it is not a problem. The warning is more of an early warning to a potential problem later. Also if 1 of say large fleet of 30 instances report high memory the environment health may still be Ok if the other metrics are fine. At present however the thresholds can't be customized.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to see if this threshold could be increased, I don't _really_ want to decrease the java memory we allocate for no other reason than to appease Elastic Beanstalk.